Selecting the right Agent Pool Service
The solution to my problem seems to be the need to assign the appropriate Agent Pool Service to my project's Contributors permission group.
How do I identify the right one? There's two dozen of them all identified with unique numbers (ex. Agent Pool Service (1)).

On the identities "Agent Pool Service (<Number>)", the "<Number>" is a poolId (ID of an agent pool).
So, the identity "Agent Pool Service (1)" is associated with the agent pool that the ID is '1'.
To get the poolId of an agent pool, you just need to open that pool on Organization Settings, then on the address bar you can get the poolId from the URL of this pool.

Note: The "Agent Pool Service (<Number>)" identities will be persisted even if the agent pool has been deleted. So, you might see many such identities in your Azure DevOps organization.

